# Hardware mixer for MIDI CC editing

Tags: midi, mixer

Is it possible to purchase a set of hardware faders that can be mapped such that each fader controls the value of a specified CC on a specified track, to control expression/dynamics in orchestral MIDI tracks?

Edit: As I hope to use the faders to remix, I would like them to be motorised and reflect the current state of the tracks at any time.

Comment: search 'midi osc'. You can even run it from a phone, if your DAW can support it.

Comment: Something like this?  https://www.thomann.de/gb/korg_nanokontrol_2_black.htm  https://www.thomann.de/gb/akai_apc_mini.htm  https://www.thomann.de/gb/behringer_x_touch.htm    https://www.thomann.de/gb/akai_apc_40_mk2.htm

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - thanks: I'm not sure. I didn't mention the faders need to be motorised to reflect the state of the track during remixing. Is it possible to map each MIDI fader to any track and CC?

Comment: Depends on the product and what other products you're using it with. I guess you'll just have to study the subject

Comment: I've studied and found nothing since my 01X died, hence the post here.  I can't be the only person wanting to do this on a budget.

Answer (score 2):

Presonus Faderport is one such device. Slap it in MIDI mode and map it in however you'd like. That process will differ depending on your DAW but any of the major ones support this

I looked into building my own motorized fader control surface at one point years ago... it's not even that difficult to DIY, I just never had the time. So you're definitely not alone and finally the market has provided a solution. There's a few brands/models out there now but the Faderport is the only one I remember off the top of my head, it looked like the best fit for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is a basic function of most 'MIDI fader' or 'Control surface'  products.